# Enviar mensagem de notificação para aplicativo

Tags: android, android-notification

Estou desenvolvendo um APP e tenho a necessidade enviar avisos aos usuários que usam este APP.
Exemplo, em APPs de sites de compras , quando surge uma promoção chega uma mensagem o Aplicativo sobre a promoção. O usuário ler e a mensagem apaga.

Como posso fazer isto?

Este APP é para uma escola, e a minha ideia é que por exemplo, a direção da escola possa através de uma página web escrever uma mensagem e que esta mensagem possa chegar aos pais que usam o APP em seu celular avisando sobre reuniões, entregas de boletim, etc.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 8):

Olá a partir do google IO 2016 o serviço de mensagem foi transferido para o Firebase o que tornou mais simples a implantação inicial, pois dispensa a necessidade de um servidor para envio das mensagens.

Adicione ao build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
}
```

Voce pode enviar mensagens pelo console do firebase que seria uma solução inicial. Depois passa para uma outra solução em php, java ou outra linguagem(que domine).

Adicione ao seu android manifest:

Para tratar as mensagens recebidas use a seguinte classe:

```
package com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Com isso seu aplicativo ja vai receber mensagens via console.
Há muito a ser feito segue a página do Firebase que tem bastante documentação e de onde eu tirei essas informações:

[Firebase Cloud Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience)

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Esse serviço chama-se **Push Notification (Cloud Messaging)**, não tem como eu te explicar com códigos pois é um serviço bem extenso.

Na documentação do Android, existe uma explicação bem eficiente:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Lá, você encontra exemplos de como trabalhar com a funcionalidade:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Dessa forma, a direção da escola através de uma página online, postam o título e a descrição do anúncio, e chegará a todos que tem o app instalado.

Qualquer dúvida posta aqui que a gente te ajuda.

Abraços.